# PHP SQL query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to get the last time my database was updated, so I use this query in my PHP code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT UPDATE_TIME
                                FROM   information_schema.tables
                                WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'map_db'
                                AND TABLE_NAME = ".$objects_tab."");
$lastUpdateTime = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo "<div id ='lastUpdate'>".$lastUpdateTime."</div>";
```

For some reason the query won't work, does anyone know whats the problem?

It works when I do other queries so its not the `$mysqli` connect variable or the table name variable that's wrong.

Comment: No quotes around the value of the table name?

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Comment: Double post proberly 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535074/sql-server-database-last-updated-date-time

Answer (score 1):

Table name value should be wrapped in single quotes:

```
"SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'map_db'
   AND TABLE_NAME = '".$objects_tab."'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's incorrect. `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array of results. You must to modify like this:

```
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo "<div id ='lastUpdate'>".$rows['lastUpdateTime']."</div>";
```

Assuming `lastUpdateTime` as the key in the database.