# How to get the time of last operation on mysql table?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I need to know the time of any change made to the database table (insert, update or delete etc). In my case I am using MySQL. I found this piece of code but it always returns the same timestamp even though I see table changing

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'strapi'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'files'
```

in the above query I am trying to access `UPDATE_TIME` for `files` table from `information_schema.tables` tables
is there any way of achieving this without additional tables ?

Comment: Then why do you tag PostgreSQL?

Comment: @UmutTEKİN and you dared to dislike my question :(

Comment: The tagging is fixed, I took it back.

Comment: According to the [official document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html#:~:text=table%20was%20created.-,UPDATE_TIME,-When%20the%20table), the issue might be fine. You need to provide information about version, operating system and database engine .

Comment: @UmutTEKİN I have mysql set to latest in my dockerfile, its running inside docker container, and MacOS ventura 13.5.2 if thats important

Comment: possible duplicate : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535074/sql-server-database-last-updated-date-time

Comment: @Nahid no, question you provided asks if its possible to know that table is altered or not, while what i need is to know the contents of the table, different thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing with:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM your_database LIKE 'your_table';
```

You need to look at the `Update_time` column.

This method has several advantages. It is a standardized way to get the information, and will also work in something like the widely used [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/). It is also properly documented in [the reference manual of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html). It explains the `Update_time` column as:

> When the data file was last updated. For some storage engines, this
> value is NULL. For example, InnoDB stores multiple tables in its
> system tablespace and the data file timestamp does not apply. Even
> with file-per-table mode with each InnoDB table in a separate .ibd
> file, change buffering can delay the write to the data file, so the
> file modification time is different from the time of the last insert,
> update, or delete. For MyISAM, the data file timestamp is used;
> however, on Windows the timestamp is not updated by updates, so the
> value is inaccurate.
>
> Update_time displays a timestamp value for the last UPDATE, INSERT, or
> DELETE performed on InnoDB tables that are not partitioned. For MVCC,
> the timestamp value reflects the COMMIT time, which is considered the
> last update time. Timestamps are not persisted when the server is
> restarted or when the table is evicted from the InnoDB data dictionary
> cache.

Which might give you some clues as to why you see the same timestamp all the time?

The crucial thing to realize is that this show you when **the data file** for the table was updated, not when the table itself was updated.

To get accurate information, about any changes, I think you have to log those yourself.

Comment: it does not work the way i expect it to. its been 3 hours and 10 files upload since the time it shows me Update_time

Comment: @howardwolowitz Yes, that's basically what I'm saying: it's not reliable or consistent. However, you can quite easily log updates yourself. Normally you would make that part of the database design itself. It's usually a simple column, for instance: `last_modified`, but more complex designs are possible. I have no idea at what stage of the design you are, and what your needs are, but accessing the INFORMATION_SCHEMA should not be a standard part of any program, it should be used for diagnostic purposes only.